# JSON decode on empty string behaves differently with PHP 7

Tags: php, json

Result on PHP 5.6

```
json_decode('', true);
echo last_json_error(); // 0
```

Result on PHP 7.0

```
json_decode('', true);
echo last_json_error(); // 4
```

I checked the changelog of PHP 7 (https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference) and could not find the reason for that. JSON got replaced by JSOND but the BC breaks list does not mention that!?

To clarify:
My question is not about valid/invalid JSON. It's about the behavior change of PHP I could not find.

Comment: uh, it clearly says why right in the json section of that page. the licensing of the original json library wasn't compatible with various distros usin php: https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#json-extension-replaced-with-jsond

Comment: @MarcB He's not asking why it was replaced, his question is about this incompatible change, which isn't mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: I think the old behavior was simply a bug. An empty string doesn't match any of the productions at www.json.org.

Comment: Technicaly, an empty string ISN'T valid json. JSON is basically just javascript, and is any value-only representation of the right-hand-side of an assignment. `var foo = this_part_is_json;`. `var foo = ;` isn't valid javascript, so an empty string can't be valid json. though the question would then by why an empty string doesn't simply encode to `""`

Comment: @MarcB The other "BC Breaks" listed in the changes are also about invalid JSON. I guess they just didn't notice this difference when they were writing the change notice.

Comment: Or maybe they just didn't think it was important enough to mention. A number like `34.` is valid in many languages, and is a very likely erroneous JSON number. But why would anyone think they could decode an empty string as JSON?

Comment: It's not about valid or invalid JSON, it is a behavior change of PHP. In my opinion it should be mentioned. There might be production code relying on that behavior.

Comment: I found the bugfix: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68938. So like Barmar stated, just a bug which got fixed.

Comment: Hurray for messy!

Answer (score 2):

It was marked as a bug and was fixed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68938

You can find change logs here: http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.0 (search for json_decode)

Comment: To summarise: the unexpected behaviour is in 5.6.5 -- an empty json string _should_ throw an error.